# what machine learning algorithm could be better for this scenario

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a dataset comprised of roughly 15M observations, with approximately 3% of it being from the interest class. I can train the model in a pc, but i need to implement the classifier in a raspberry pi3. Since the raspberry has such a limited memory, what algorithms represent the least load for it?.

Additional info: the dataset is hard to differentiate. For example, ANNs can't get past the 80% detection rate for the interest class, no matter the architecture or activation function. Random forest has demonstrated great performance but the number of trees and nodes required aren't feasible for the implementation on a microcontroller.

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: The main question is about what is the performance you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially trim the trees in Random Forest approach so that to balance the classifier performance with memory / processing power requirements.

Also, I am suspecting you have a strongly imbalanced train/test sets so I wonder if you used any of the approaches suggested in this case (e.g. SMOTE, ADASYN, etc.). In case of python I strongly suggest reviewing [`imbalanced-learn`](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/) library. Using such an approach could lead to a reduced size of classifier with acceptably good performance that you would be able to fit to run on the target device.

Last but not least, this question could easily go to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) sites.

Comment: Is it possible to implement a random forest (classification only) with the 1GB of memory available in the raspberry?

Comment: Could you please upvote/mark the answer if you find it useful?